# Excel hyperlink causing multiple calls to the .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, hyperlink, navigation

I have an excel sheet with hyperlink with query string to a Webpage(.aspx).

[image: Screenshot of Excel Hyperlink]

Upon clicking the hyperlink, Webpage is being called multiple times (breakpoint gets hit atleast thrice).

But, same url when opened from email or directly doesn't trigger multiple calls.

Is this normal? Why is it happening like this only with excel? How can I fix this behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

I've tried debugging to see if the calls are postback calls, but they're not (IsPostback is false). Unable to find the cause of the repeated calls.

Comment: That's just how office "works". Checking if the page exists, and the `OPTIONS` that are allowed, or if the link is on a WEBDAV server.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Can we avoid this behavior as it is making the Query String null in the subsequent calls, which is not rendering the expected result.